# Laplacian Matrix Calculation in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I have been trying to implement the Digital Matting algorithm described in the research paper named [Learning Based Digital Matting](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5459326).

Its MATLAB Code is available [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31412-learning-based-digital-matting). I am trying to convert the MATLAB code into C++ using OpenCV 2.4.3 and UMFPACK.

The problem is that the function named `getLap_iccv09_overlapping` (that calculates the Laplacian Matrix of input image) is not available off-the-shelf in OpenCV and I have to write my own implementation in cpp. I am getting incorrect results from my implementation.

Is there any C/C++ library that offers [Laplacian Matrix calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of a matrix/image?

Comment: It is interesting Laplacian matrix is calculated for a graph. How image is represented as graph in CV ?

Comment: Laplacian is a sparse matrix. The function takes an image and a background mask as input, and gives Sparse Laplacian matrix as output.

Comment: Laplacian matrix calculation of a graph is not a complex thing. The real problem here is - How these two images are represented as a graph ? There must be some algorithm step which analyzes these images, extracts some features and represents them as a graph. From here Laplacian matrix calculation is trivial. (It seems that there is intermediate crucial step which calculates an image/feature graph, but I may be wrong.)

Comment: Any progress with that?

Answer (score 1):

I've recently have had to "translate" several Matlab functions to C++ (using OpenCV) and unfortunately you can't find the exact same function. There are some similar functions but the results are not exactly the same, especially with the borders of matrices.
I would suggest that you read and understand the algorithms (the operations on the matrices) used by your Matlab function and write it in c++ (Opencv is great for matrix operations).
You can test it by using a small matrix (4 by 4 for instance) and proceeding step by step, first with the elements inside the matrix then with the edges and borders (I find the border conditions to be more difficult to understand)
Good Luck!

Comment: Actually I have done all of the things you mentioned, but i'm not getting the correct output. Also, the algorithm skips the image boundries.

Comment: Can you post the original matlab algorithme and the one you translated in c++ ?

Comment: I can post, but the C++ code is very large.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this function](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html#cv-laplacian) not sufficient?

Comment: This function applies laplace operator to the image. [Applying Laplace Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) and [Calculating Laplacian Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) are two different things.

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood. I can't really help here but maybe [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18945/understanding-the-properties-and-use-of-the-laplacian-matrix-and-its-norm) can perhaps help you find a use for this function after all, since it seems the laplacian matrix is a discrete analogue of the laplacian operator. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

How similar are your Matlab and C++ versions of the function? It sounds like you'll probably just need to step through the various stages checking that the various intermediate results are the same, and try and find the error that way.

You might find use for [writeMat.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/attachment/ticket/1342/writeMat.cpp) which is a function available to take your OpenCV cv::Mat matrix and save it as a Matlab .m file which should make comparison easier - write out a .m at various points in your cpp code, load them into Matlab, run the Matlab script and compare at the appropriate points.